# Getting Django / NGINX / uWSGI to work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I've setup my digitalocean droplet with Ubuntu 14.04. NGINX, uWSGI and a django application which i'm trying to get running.

Could someone please help me out? I think i've had almost every tutorial I could find on these combination of tools. And cant find out what's wrong with my configuration, already tried a crazy amount of things.

This is my project file structure:

```
-- var
    -- www
        -- myproject
            |-- env/
            |-- conf/
            |   |-- myproject.sock
            |   `-- uwsgi.ini
            `-- public/
                |-- manage.py
                |-- media/
                |-- project.db
                |-- requirements.txt
                |-- static/
                `-- website/
                    |-- dev/
                    |-- gulp/
                    |-- gulpfile.js
                    |-- package.json
                    |-- settings.py
                    |-- static/
                    |-- templates/
                    |-- urls.py
                    `-- wsgi.py
```

I installed everything in a virtualenv in the `env/` folder of my project.

Just serving the django app by typing `python manage.py runserver` works, I can view it by browsing my webservers IP.

These are my current config files:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.nl www.myproject.nl;

    root /var/www/myproject/public/;
    access_log /var/www/myproject/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/myproject/logs/error.log;

    location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
        alias /var/www/myproject/public/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
        alias /var/www/myproject/public/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/myproject/conf/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

/var/www/project/conf/uwsgi.conf

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = myproject
projectdomain = myproject.nl
base = /var/www/myproject

# config
plugins = python
home = ../env
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=website.settings
pythonpath = %(base)/public
module = website.wsgi:application
wsgi-file = %(base)/public/website/wsgi.py
socket = %(projectname).sock
```

I tried running the .ini file by typing `uwsgi --ini /var/www/myproject/conf/uwsgi.ini` and it does execute, but doesn't seem to set up the server.

When browsing the domain name i see the 'Welcome to nginx!' page so i think it has to do with the uWSGi config.

Comment: Your nginx config is in sites-available; have you actually enabled it?

Comment: I symlinked it to sites-enabled...

Comment: You are create /var/www/project/conf/uwsgi.conf but using uwsgi --ini /var/www/myproject/conf/uwsgi.ini command. Wrong name?

Comment: Not working on this project anymore, but the paths and the tree in the code blocks were the actual paths. So that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think path to your socket file is incorrect.
But anyway, 'Welcome to nginx!' means nginx does not even try to relay anything to uwsgi. If uwsgi was broken, you would see a 502.

I see your config is in `sites-available`. Did you symlink it to `sites-enabled`?

Comment: I don't know how the fix the path then, it looks like it's pointing correctly.. And I did try to run the .ini with `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` from the conf folder..
Also i symlinked the file to sites-enabled..